# How do I jump to the next/prev diff in GIT difftool?

Tags: git, vim, difftool

I am using git difftool to compare 2 large files in VIM. I want to navigate only to the lines that differ.

How do I navigate quickly between lines that differ using GIT difftool ?

I am looking for something like winmerge shortcut keys :
Alt+down  - Next Change
Alt+Up    - Prev Change

Comment: Apologies, I am pretty new to VIM

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`vim` Has an extensive and pretty good helpfile. You would do yourself a favour trying to familiarize yourself with it.

from `:h diff`

```
3. Jumping to diffs                 *jumpto-diffs*

Two commands can be used to jump to diffs:
                                *[c*
    [c      Jump backwards to the previous start of a change.
            When a count is used, do it that many times.
                                *]c*
    ]c      Jump forwards to the next start of a change.
            When a count is used, do it that many times.
```

Comment: I decided to use F5 and F6, by adding these lines to `.vimrc` : `noremap <F5> [c` and `noremap <F6> ]c`

Comment: In my vimrc, those are already taken to maximimize/normalize my window. The `]` and `[` are hard to reach but it's used in so many places *(tmux, vim, ctags)* that I decided to join them io trying to beat them.

Comment: @Flimm could you comment how to set it to be on F5 & F6 ?